# подскажите слушателя в JS

Tags: javascript, события

addEventListener('слушатеь',()=>{})

подскажите слушателя который следит за изменением ширины окна браузера.

в чем промах ?
не хочет присваивать пнгшку обратно.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {


    if (document.body.clientWidth <= 800) {

        document.querySelector('.glob_wrap').style.background = "transparent";

    } else if (document.body.clientWidth >= 801) {

        document.querySelector('.glob_wrap').style.backgroundImage = "url(./img/bg.png) no-repeat;";


    }
})
```

Comment: Просто из любопытства - почему не используете [Медиа-запросы](https://webref.ru/css/value/media)? Кстати, в JS так же есть нечто подобное - [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) и всё, что [к нему прилагается](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries).

Comment: Забыл добавить, что код ваш будет [абсолютно рабочий](https://jsfiddle.net/9uvzd2bg/), нужно только `no-repeat;`  убрать ;) И дело тут вовсе не в "слушателях" или чем-то еще

Comment: Медиа использовал, возможно знаешь как в медиа у класса допостим, убрать значение. вот был у него бэкграунд, а нужно удалить его вовсе ?

Comment: Под словом "вовсе" вы что понимаете? Что бы он больше ни при каких условиях не появился или всё-таки при одном условии фон был, а при другом - нет?

Comment: Уже разобрался, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {
  console.log("resize");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', e => {})
```